# Unspecified error while building setup project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, setup-project, gmap.net

I have created a simple Windows Form application in C#, that is based on gmap.net package, and I will be using it in offline mode, so I downloaded several layers of of specific portion of the map, and the total size of 25 GB.

And then when I created a setup project for this application and configuring it as needed, I built this setup project of course, but the setup project wasn't getting built, and the error I am getting is related to the map file.

Of course the folder containing the map is included in the initial project of the app. The Windows form is building right.

The error I get is:

> ERROR: Could not find file '<Path_to_file>\Data.gmdb' 'Unspecified error'

//<Path_to_file> is added by me, but the path showing in the error is the right path where the file exist

The following screenshot shows the structure of the solution:

[image: Solution Structure]

What might be the cause of this error? Is it the large size of the maps file?

And I need to mention that publishing the Windows Forms project alone is working fine even with the maps file. But I need to use the setup project file for installation.

If anyone has a clue what might that error mean because it is unspecified.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/233556/handling-big-files-in-visual-studio-setup-projects

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant , that is excatly what i want.